# Combining pathes along edges with the for-c-command directive of forest

Tags: linguistics, forest

Rereading the `forest` manual, I discovered the `for-c-command` directive, which does something to all nodes that are c-commanded by a certain other node. For instance drawing them in red. I wonder whether this could be combined with the very cool solution to [Drawing lines or arrows along node pathes with forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352873/drawing-lines-or-arrows-along-node-pathes-with-forest/353262). So: Is it possible to draw arrows from a certain node to all other nodes that it c-commands?

Comment: No example, then?

Answer (score 2):

This looks ugly, but it should illustrate how to solve the main problem: how to easily squeeze the name of the c-commanding node into `\draw` code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [CP
    [C,
      for c-commanded/.process=Ow{name}{tikz={\draw[->](#1)--();}}
    ]
    [TP
      [T]
      [VP
        [DP]
        [V'
          [V]
          [DP]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And integrated with solution from the hobby answer:

```
\documentclass[convert=png]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\forestset{%
  walkfromto@toLCA/.nodewalk style={
    save={walkfromto@anc}{load={walk last},ancestors},
    walk and save={walk from first to LCA}{
      fake=parent,
      while={}{
        if in saved nodewalk={current}{walkfromto@anc}
        {break}
        {
          % This doesn't work:
          %%%% fake={walkfromto@toLCA={#1}}
          % "save" introduces an embedded nodewalk, which doesn't restore the value
          % of "fake" after doing its work ... (will be) fixed in v2.1.5
          % So instead of saying "current" below, whoever uses this style must
          % appropriately define walkfromto@toLCA@step.
          walkfromto@toLCA@step,
          fake=parent
        },
      },
    },
  },
  walkfromto@fromLCA/.nodewalk style={% we're at LCA now
    walk and save={walk from LCA to last}{
      if in saved nodewalk={current}{walk last}{% other = LCA
      }{
        reverse/.process=Ow{id}{
          fake={load={walk last},parent},
          until={>O_={id}{##1}}{current,fake=parent}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  define long step={LCA}{n args=2}{
    fake={group={#1}},
    % In v2.1.5, replace this workaround by "fake={walkfromto@toLCA={#2}}"
    walkfromto@toLCA@step/.style={fake=current}, walkfromto@toLCA={#2},
    % end of workaround (do the same in all step definitions below)
    current
  },
  define long step={walk from to}{n args=2}{
    save={walk last}{group={#2}},
    walk and save={walk first}{group={#1}},
    walkfromto@toLCA@step/.style={current}, walkfromto@toLCA={#2},
    walk and save={walk LCA}{current},
    walkfromto@fromLCA,
    load={walk last},
  },
  between nodewalk steps/.style 2 args={
    for nodewalk={#1}{every step={options/.process=OOw2{!b.name}{name}{#2}}}
  },
  hobby curve/.style 2 args={
    for nodewalk={walk from to={current}{#1}}{},
    temptoksa={},
    temptoksb={},
    pass through/.style={
      temptoksa+/.register=temptoksb,temptoksb={..},
      temptoksa+/.process=Ow{name}{##1}},
    for load={walk from first to LCA}{
      pass through={([yshift=2.5pt]##1.north east)}},
    for load={walk LCA}{
      pass through={([yshift=4.5pt]##1.south)}},
    for load={walk from LCA to last}{
      pass through={([yshift=2.5pt]##1.north west)}},
    between nodewalk steps={load=walk first,load=walk last}{
      !r.tikz+/.process=Rw{temptoksa}{%
        \draw[#2] (##1.north)
        to [curve through={####1}]
        (##2.north);
      }},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [CP
    [C,
      for c-commanded/.process=Ow{name}{hobby curve={name=#1}{red,<-}}
    ]
    [TP
      [T]
      [VP
        [DP]
        [V'
          [V]
          [DP]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And now a rudimentary attempt at tweaking the arrows. I modified `hobby curve` style so that `shift`s are now parameters; in the call of hobby, the shift is computed wrt to level difference. Far from ideal, but maybe a start ...

```
\documentclass[convert=png]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\forestset{%
  walkfromto@toLCA/.nodewalk style={
    save={walkfromto@anc}{load={walk last},ancestors},
    walk and save={walk from first to LCA}{
      fake=parent,
      while={}{
        if in saved nodewalk={current}{walkfromto@anc}
        {break}
        {
          % This doesn't work:
          %%%% fake={walkfromto@toLCA={#1}}
          % "save" introduces an embedded nodewalk, which doesn't restore the value
          % of "fake" after doing its work ... (will be) fixed in v2.1.5
          % So instead of saying "current" below, whoever uses this style must
          % appropriately define walkfromto@toLCA@step.
          walkfromto@toLCA@step,
          fake=parent
        },
      },
    },
  },
  walkfromto@fromLCA/.nodewalk style={% we're at LCA now
    walk and save={walk from LCA to last}{
      if in saved nodewalk={current}{walk last}{% other = LCA
      }{
        reverse/.process=Ow{id}{
          fake={load={walk last},parent},
          until={>O_={id}{##1}}{current,fake=parent}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  define long step={LCA}{n args=2}{
    fake={group={#1}},
    % In v2.1.5, replace this workaround by "fake={walkfromto@toLCA={#2}}"
    walkfromto@toLCA@step/.style={fake=current}, walkfromto@toLCA={#2},
    % end of workaround (do the same in all step definitions below)
    current
  },
  define long step={walk from to}{n args=2}{
    save={walk last}{group={#2}},
    walk and save={walk first}{group={#1}},
    walkfromto@toLCA@step/.style={current}, walkfromto@toLCA={#2},
    walk and save={walk LCA}{current},
    walkfromto@fromLCA,
    load={walk last},
  },
  between nodewalk steps/.style 2 args={
    for nodewalk={#1}{every step={options/.process=OOw2{!b.name}{name}{#2}}}
  },
  hobby curve/.style n args=4{
    for nodewalk={walk from to={current}{#1}}{},
    temptoksa={},
    temptoksb={},
    pass through/.style={
      temptoksa+/.register=temptoksb,temptoksb={..},
      temptoksa+/.process=Ow{name}{##1}},
    for load={walk from first to LCA}{
      pass through={([#3]##1.north east)}},
    for load={walk LCA}{
      pass through={([#4]##1.south)}},
    for load={walk from LCA to last}{
      pass through={([#3]##1.north west)}},
    between nodewalk steps={load=walk first,load=walk last}{
      !r.tikz+/.process=Rw{temptoksa}{%
        \draw[#2] (##1.north)
        to [curve through={####1}]
        (##2.north);
      }},
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [CP
    [C,
      for c-commanded/.process=OOw2{name}{level}{hobby curve/.process=
        __ Ow+dw Ow+dw
        {name=#1}{red,<-}
        {level}{2pt*(##1-#2+1)}{shift={(##1,##1)}}
        {level}{4pt*(##1-#2+1)}{shift={(##1,##1)}}
      }
    ]
    [TP
      [T]
      [VP
        [DP]
        [V'
          [V]
          [DP]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Theoretically nice! (+1, obviously.)